# Installing Switch.pm in Active perl on windows 10

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a Perl script running on Windows 10 with Active Perl 5.28.1. It currently runs on windows 7 with Active Perl 5.8.8.  When I try to run it I get:

```
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: C:\Perl\lib C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at fds_propagator_with_collision_ephem.pl line 108.
```

So I tried to install `Switch.pm`.  I started `cpan` and then did `install Switch.pm`

I got:

```
C:\Users\rdirosar>cpan
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.20)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan> install Switch.pm

Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163, <IN> line 1.

'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
............................................................................DONE

Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.
'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
.Could not split line["┬0\cL²\cU\c?└'≈\cCé"]

Could not split line["c▐X'Γπ"├█\cP\cE?▀&δ┌╠5α%â╛mτl∞Bô⌠ñg▒R\cI¥\cT\cP╘≈\cX."]


Could not split line["V╟\c]\$≈»1"]

Could not split line["a\cVk\cQ0y│ôδNj+╒1<c;¼òPb╪Zà⌠∞\cBl≥┤h\cRU\cPFÄ┴▄4û\cIƒ\@⌐╜─b*QZ\$lEX╞╔■î>∩îÅ=\cF┬N;│¼-\cZu¿fÆh\eD"]

Giving up parsing your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsReading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'

Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.


'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
............................................................................DONE

Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'

Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.


'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.

Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to happen.

Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.

Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.

.Could not split line["┬0\cL²\cU\c?└'≈\cCé"]

Could not split line["c▐X'Γπ"├█\cP\cE?▀&δ┌╠5α%â╛mτl∞Bô⌠ñg▒R\cI¥\cT\cP╘≈\cX."]

Could not split line["V╟\c]\$≈»1"]

Could not split line["a\cVk\cQ0y│ôδNj+╒1<c;¼òPb╪Zà⌠∞\cBl≥┤h\cRU\cPFÄ┴▄4û\cIƒ\@⌐╜─b*QZ\$lEX╞╔■î>∩îÅ=\cF┬N;│¼-\cZu¿fÆh\eD"]

Giving up parsing your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsLockfile removed.

C:\Users\rdirosar>
```

I tried deleting the files in:
`C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors` and `C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\`
That had no effect, if there are files in the directories they are updated 
as needed.

What am I doing wrong?
Robert

note: I found I needed to add some cr/lf to the text, otherwise I would get a error message about code not being formated correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)?

Comment: The module is named `Switch`, not `Switch.pm` (that's the filename). Please note that the concept of switch-case in Perl has [subtle complexity](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when), and `Switch` is an old implementation of this that has [even worse problems](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch#BUGS).

Comment: Strawberry Perl is not an option.  We must use Active Perl from Active State.

Comment: "Install Switch" produces the same result.  I am porting existing code, not writing new code.  The Perl script is 6000+ lines, I would prefer to not change it, if possible.  Plan A is to port the code unchanged.

Comment: Doesn't AP have its own non standard way to install modules?

Comment: What's the output of `echo o conf | cpan`?

Comment: Switch is used in many places, the script is 6000+ lines.

Comment: >What's the output of echo o conf | cpan?  The output is 3300+ characters, but I can only post 600.  Is there a way of posting a large comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.activestate.com/blog/goodbye-ppm-hello-state-tool/ ActivePerl 5.28 has removed the old PPM interactive GUI module installation tool in favor of the new https://platform.activestate.com/ website where you log in, pick modules, builds, waits and finally downloads your own custom runtime as one big .exe or .msi file (on windows anyways).

This installation file includes ActivePerl 5.28 *and* the modules you picked.

In my test on Windows 10 the `Switch` module was installed without trouble like this.

Other alternatives might be:

- Perl 5.26 where PPM a is still available I think, find it at activestate.com
- use the CPAN command from 5.28, but for many if not most modules you need `make` or `dmake`. The latter is perhaps easiest available through http://www.mingw.org/
- Use WSL - [windows subsystem for linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). There `apt` or `yum` or similar command for your flavour of linux are available. Easy and dependable way to install Perl modules. In my experience. But this isn't ActivePerl, it's barely Windows, it's mostly Gnu/Linux
- Strawberry-Perl for Windows
- Switch seems to be (judging by a very quick glance now) just a pure perl module that does not depend on other non-core modules. So you can just download the file from https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/CHORNY/Switch-2.17/Switch.pm and place it in one of the folders output from `perl -le'print for @INC'` and make sure the file is readable by the system user.

Comment: So the best choice is the first one, go to the https://platform.activestate.com/ link, login and then you get a GUI that lets you build the modulates on their system, and then download a complte Perl package that you install on your system.

Comment: I wont claim "the best choice" just by the very quick test I did, but it worked for me. And if you're going to stick with ActiveState, then it's probably best to learn about their Platform thing anyway. Also I added another alternative at the bottom of the list in my answer above.

Comment: Now I see, great  :-)